# I can' t open settings or login as anyother user except admin

Tags: unity, gnome, pulseaudio, logout, shotwell

I cannot open my system settings or a few native applications like videos, shotwell, rhythmbox. Whenever I try opening any of these my system reboots or logsout I'm not sure which because the applications I was running then would all be closed but there is no palpable time delay for a reboot and there is no BIOS screen shown.

I enabled something like automatic login , which was the last time I was able to open my settings. I tried removing and adding `unity-control-center` and `gnome-control-center` nothing worked. If I check the logs  there is some error like this

`[pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.`

and after which there is always another log entry

`CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....`
and

`Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop`

There is nothing stopping me from opening any other applications that I have installed and I am repeatedly bugged to enter my admin password for every single installation and for some reason I cannot login into any other user except admin.

**UPDATE**
I can't even open the properties of files in Nautilus file explorer the same shutdown/logoff thing happens.

Comment: Sounds as if your home folder is messed up. Open a terminal and run `sudo chown -R $USER: $HOME`.

Comment: @mook765 nope. That's just not it . does not work. Still the same. Know any other workarounds ? Thank you for the effort though.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on here, the error messages aren't very helpful either.  Enabling autologin shouldn't create such problems. You'd need to be much more specific ( saying "I enabled autologin"s not enough, how you did it is also relevant). What does "nothing worked" mean", couldn't you reinstall the packages or could you, but the problem is still there. Ubuntu flavour and version etc...